# how to insert a delimiter every nth column using shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I've data as follows

```
11111 22222 33333 44444                       55555           66666
```

I would like the output data as follows

```
11111,22222,3333,4444                       ,55555           ,66666
```

I tried using the tr command by converting the space with commas but get all commas after the 4444 OR 55555. Note: there is a lot of spaces between 4444 and 5555. Is it possible to fill the space at the 6th, 12th, 17th, 46th,etc column with a comma ?

Comment: just thinking out loud here but try replacing spaces with commas then after replace `,,` with ` ` (space)

Comment: Do you really want one less `3` and one less `4` in the output?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I was able to resolve this issue. since the field where I had to insert a comma was constant I used multiple sed command. so for the above example the cmd was

Comment: echo "11111 22222 33333 44444                       55555           66666" |sed 's/./,/6;s/./,/12;s/./,/18'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your actual Input_file is same as shown sample then following may help you too in same.

```
awk '{gsub(/ [0-9]+/,",&");gsub(/, /,",")} 1'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
11111,22222,33333,44444                      ,55555          ,66666
```

Explanation of above command:

```
awk '{
gsub(/ [0-9]+/,",&"); ##gsub is awk utility to substitute things, so its format is gsub(regex_for_strings_to_be_replaced,with_whom_it_should_be_replaced,variable/line). So here I am substituting globally space then all digits(continuous ones) with a comma and (matched regex itself, which is space then all digits(continuous ones)).
gsub(/, /,",")        ##Using gsub again here to replace comma then space(, ) with only comma(,), to get the output into same shape in which OP has asked, it will remove space between command and digits which was created in above command.
}
1                     ##awk works on method of condition then action, so here I am making condition as TRUE by mentioning 1 and not mentioning any action so be default print action will happen, print of current line.
' Input_file          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't this just do what you are looking for? (guessing the missing 4 in your desired output is a typo)

```
sed -E 's/ ([0-9])/,\1/g' data
```

(use `-r` instead of `-E` if you are on a mac).

Comment: Actually, macOS's `sed` is based on an old version they grabbed from FreeBSD, which supports `-E` but not `-r`. FreeBSD (and other BSDs) have supported both options equivalently for years. The `-E` is intended to be equivalent to grep's `-E` option (for "Extended" RE). I'm not sure where the GNU folks got the idea of using `-r` for ERE.